# Sharepoint CheckOut method REST API using C#

Tags: sharepoint-designer, rest

I try to create a C# program which opens a document in checkout mode. 
How can I use REST API checkout method on C#. 
Secondly I will add checkout operation windows context menu, user can open documents without using sharepoint on iexplorer.

Comment: try this api. ---> site url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/file name')/CheckOut()

Comment: You can also use CSOM